# Python client for multipart form with CAS

Tags: python, urllib2, cas, python-requests

I am trying to write a Python script to POST a multipart form to a site that requires authentication through CAS.

There are two approaches that both solve part of the problem:

1. The Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) library works well for submitting multipart forms.
2. There is caslib, with a [login](http://packages.python.org/caslib/caslib.html#caslib.login_to_cas_service) function. It returns an OpenerDirector that can presumably be used for further requests.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get a complete solution out what I have so far.
There are just some ideas from a couple hours of research; I am open to just about any solution that works.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`poster`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/poster/) to prepare multipart/form-data. Try to pass poster's opener to the caslib and use caslib's opener to make requests (not tested):

```
import urllib2

import caslib
import poster.encode
import poster.streaminghttp

opener = poster.streaminghttp.register_openers()
r, opener = caslib.login_to_cas_service(login_url, username, password,
                                        opener=opener)    
params = {'file': open("test.txt", "rb"), 'name': 'upload test'}
datagen, headers = poster.encode.multipart_encode(params)
response = opener.open(urllib2.Request(upload_url, datagen, headers))
print response.read()
```

Comment: I tried that and the post didn't work, but I think the problem was something else, like some header stuff or something. But I at least got through the CAS security, so I think that @J.F. Sebastian's answer is correct...

Answer (score 1):

I accepted J.F. Sebastian's answer because I think it was closest to what I'd asked, but I actually wound up getting it to work by using [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), Python library for web browser automation.

```
import argparse
import mechanize
import re
import sys

# (SENSITIVE!) Authentication info
username = r'username'
password = r'password'

# Command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Submit lab to CS 235 site (Winter 2013)')
parser.add_argument('lab_num', help='Lab submission number')
parser.add_argument('file_name', help='Submission file (zip)')
args = parser.parse_args()

# Go to login site
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('https://cas.byu.edu/cas/login?service=https%3a%2f%2fbeta.cs.byu.edu%2f~sub235%2fsubmit.php')

# Login and forward to submission site
br.form = br.forms().next()
br['username'] = username
br['password'] = password
br.submit()

# Submit
br.form = br.forms().next()
br['labnum'] = list(args.lab_num)
br.add_file(open(args.file_name), 'application/zip', args.file_name)
r = br.submit()

for s in re.findall('<h4>(.+?)</?h4>', r.read()):
    print s
```

Comment: you should probably mark this answer as accepted, given that other answers do not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Authentication Handler for Requests using caslib. Then you could do something like:

```
auth = CasAuthentication("url", "login", "password")
response = requests.get("http://example.com/cas_service", auth=auth)
```

Or if you're making tons of requests against the website:

```
s = requests.session()
s.auth = auth

s.post('http://casservice.com/endpoint', data={'key', 'value'}, files={'filename': '/path/to/file'})
```

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob here. What would it take to write an AuthenticationHandler?

Comment: Not a terrible lot. There's a base mix-in that's provided.